# Remove line between first and last point ( line-chart/flot.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, charts, linechart

How can I removed link between first and the last point, I tried many thing but nothing happened

I tried to google it, but I found question for mathlab!

Chart image:

[image: Chart image]

my chart code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <?php   $counter_days = 1;?>
    var ticks = [
                    @foreach($numbers_of_visitors_last_10_days as $keys=>$dates )
                    @if($counter_days <=1)
            [{{ltrim($keys,'0')}}, "days {{ltrim($keys,'0')}}"],
                    @else
            [{{ltrim($keys,'0')}},{{ltrim($keys,'0')}}],
                @endif
            <?php   $counter_days ++;?>
                @endforeach
        ];

        /*
         * LINE CHART
         * ----------
         */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";

        var line_data2 = [

                @foreach($numbers_of_visitors_last_10_days as $keys=>$dates )
            [{{ltrim($keys,'0')}}, {{count($dates)}}],
            @endforeach
        ];
        var xaxisLabel = $("<div class='axisLabel xaxisLabel'></div>")
            .text("My X Label")
            .appendTo($('#line-chart'));

        $.plot("#line-chart", [line_data2], {

            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderColor: "#E2E6EE",
                borderWidth: 1,
                tickColor: "#E2E6EE"
            },


            series: {
                shadowSize: 2,
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            colors: ["#333333", "#cccccc"],
            lines: {
                fill: true,
            },
            yaxis: {
                show: true,
                tickFormatter: function (val, axis) { return val }


            },
            xaxis: {
                show: true,
                ticks: ticks,


            }

        });


    });


</script>
```

As you see in the picture the first line is connected with the last line and it make it looks weird and unreadable

is that possible ?

Comment: Good question - unfortunately nobody seems to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1572) dellitsa wrote:

> Hi, I had the same issue when I was plotting with dates. It's not the
>   library's problem. Your data are not in the correct order. Try adding
>   order by date to your query and the plot will be fine.

This actually applies to my problem - but it was a bit different, due to an error in my SQL, I had multiplied the series, so that the same data was repeated in that array over and over, leading to the effect of "wrong order".